# Seeking Sidekicks

Tags: knowledge, mazes, video-games

<sub>Video game theme period has ended but have another puzzle anyway.</sub>

---

You're in some sort of apartment of interconnecting rooms. The below map materializes in your hands (so magical), highlighting that you are in **Room ***.

```
 A B C D E
 F G H 1 I J
 K L 2 * M N
 O P Q 3 R S
   T U V W X
     Y Z
```

A message appears on the floor on which you stand (more magic)!

> `Colour?`
>   `↑ Red or Pink`
>   `↓ Blue or Orange`
>   `← Green or Camouflage`

You then realize that you're completely alone, but you really shouldn't be? Weren't there two others with you? Maybe this clue will lead you to your missing party.

Depending on who you are, you should be able to find them following the floor clues. Search for one, then the other, in either order. When you encounter an occupied room, you'll have the option to use two teleportation runes:

**~** is a restart rune that will send you and any partner with you back to Room * with the initial floor clue. Your partner will accompany you in your new search. If you happen to encounter a stranger, they'll remain in their room; you can't recruit them.

**@** is an exit rune that will send you and your party back to your home world, but it would only activate if you find your other two members.

*So...*

- *Who are you?*
- *Who are they?*
- *What path did you use to find them?*

  (may vary, for confirming that you didn't cheat by "jumping ahead")
- *Finally, where is your home world?*

Oh, you're not the only one searching for someone else, as you'll come to discover. *How would they answer?*

Good luck!

**Room 1**

> `Gender?`
>  `← He`
>  `→ She`
>  `↑ It`

**Room 2**

> `Outfit?`
>  `← Hat, overalls, facial hair`
>  `↓ Long coat or saddle and shoes`

**Room 3**

> `Description?`
>  `→ Round and glowy`
>  `↓ Mechanically-inclined`

**Room A**

> `Backed yourself in a corner`
>  `↓ No big deal: this should take you back on your path`

**Room B**

> `You taking the scenic route?`
>  `← Sure!`
>  `↓ Oops!`

**Room C**

> *`"The Enrichment Centre reminds you to ignore any advice given."`*
>    **~ @**

**Room D**

> `Movement?`
>  `← Resting on one of six sides`
>  `→ Running on all four legs`

**Room E**

> *`"Neigh!"`*
>    **~ @**

**Room F**

> `Favourite things?`
>  `↑ Eggs and red herrings`
>  `↓ Emeralds`

**Room G**

> `Defence?`
>  `← Punch and roll`
>  `↑ Smoke screen`

**Room H**

> `← More rival than friend?`

**Room I**

> `Gift to you?`
>  `→ Curve ball`
>  `↑ Ride for a song`
>  `↓ Bandana and bountiful bullets`

**Room J**

> `Dead end. You are likely to be eaten by a...`
>  `← Quick U-turn`

**Room K**

> *`"Monotreme with dreadlocks? Chaos!"`*
>    **~ @**

**Room L**

> *`"Let's-a go, Bro!"`*
>    **~ @**

**Room M**

> *`"I'm no rookie! You can shoot me if I slow you down."`*
>    **~ @**

**Room N**

> *`"Hey! Listen!"`*
>    **~ @**

**Room O**

> *`"I'm not in a locker this time, and my pants are dry!"`*
>    **~ @**

**Room P**

> `← Nerd with Stockholm Syndrome and an Oedipal complex?`

**Room Q**

> `Classification?`
>  `← Man`
>  `↓ Beast`

**Room R**

> `Popular fan opinion?`
>  `→ Annoyingly helpful`
>  `↓ Homicidally endearing`

**Room S**

> `Would make a better guide than these magical floor clues?`
>  `↑ Sure!`
>  `↓ Would rather find own path`

**Room T**

> *`"This little vulpine can fly and swim...unlike you."`*
>    **~ @**

**Room U**

> `Classification?`
>  `← Mammal-like`
>  `↓ Reptile-like`

**Room V**

> `Movement?`
>  `← Sometimes, briefly, like a helicopter`
>  `→ Sometimes, briefly, with a stolen body - not in a potato`

**Room W**

> *`"This little idiot would like you to take a test."`*
>    **~ @**

**Room X**

> `Backed yourself in a corner`
>  `↑ About-face`

**Room Y**

> *`"Let's flutter jump out of here."`*
>    **~ @**

**Room Z**

> `How did you get here?!`
>  `You got in this doorless room; you figure a way out.`

Comment: I got stuck in room Z    :(

Comment: Are the spoiler tags really necessary? The information seems essential to solving it and it's just a nuisance to have to hover over it

Comment: @IvoBeckers I did the clues that way to avoid revealing clues before one gets to them and to mimic a maze, but they don't have to be hidden. Anyone seconds an edit for block tags instead?

Comment: It's not pretty but a "select all" or copy and paste into Notepad would be a workaround for better legibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these characters:

> Luigi through 2L, Yoshi through 2QUY, Knuckles from Sonic the Hedgehog through 1HGFK, Tails through 3VUT, Navi from Legend of Zelda through 3RSN, Epona through 1DE, Wheatley from Portal through 3RW, the Companion Cube through 1DC, Otakon from Metal Gear Solid through 2QPO, and Meryl through 1IM.

That makes the possible answers

> Mario, Sonic, Link, Chell, and Solid Snake

and the homeworlds

> The Mushroom Kingdom, Mobius, Hyrule, Aperture Science, and... wherever Metal Gear takes place.

Comment: Great! You're just missing one more group.

Comment: @Mythi: That's what I figured, but I'm not familiar with whatever series M and O are from... still looking for it.

Comment: @Mythi: I'm thinking Otakon from Metal Gear? Which would make the main character Snake. Not sure which one M is though - never played any of the games,

Comment: M would be Meryl from MGS1, that's a quote from her.

Comment: There you go! This is why it's trivia. I tried to make a trivia-less video game puzzle, but then I got sidetracked with this.

Answer (score 1):

I am

> Link (The Legend of Zelda)

and I found

> Navi and Epona

through the paths

> 3RSN and 1IE.